# Linear Dependence / Independence of Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $\{A_1, A_2, ..., A_k\}$ is a linearly independent subset of $M_{n \times n}(F)$, is $\{A_1^n, A_2^n, ..., A_k^n\}$ also linearly independent for $n > 1, n \in  \mathbb{Z^+}$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, let $A_1, ..., A_k$ be $k$ many independent matrices with zero entries on and below diagonal... Then all $A_j^n=0$.